# Can't make Item name appear when going to different page

Tags: php, html

I am making a store for a school project and I am having a hard time making text of the item name and price be saved in a variable then shown on the checkout page.

My code for the item description looks like this:

```
<div id="section">
    <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/71nodfoCvyL._SL1500_.jpg" alt="HTML         tutorial" style="width:152px;height:172px;border:0;" align="right">
    <?php $item->name='ASUS M32CD Desktop'; $item->price='549.99'; $i++; ?>
    <h4>ASUS M32CD Desktop</h4>
    <h6> $549.99 </h6>
    <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="item<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $item->name.'#'.$item->price; ?>">
&nbsp;Buy
```

When I select it and press purchase, it takes me to the checkout page but doesn't have the items listed. My checkout page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- HardDrive1.html -->
<!-- Jan 22, 2016 -->
<html>
<head>
  <title>Order Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Please Input All Information to Complete Your Order</h3>
<?php echo $item->name; ?>
<?php echo $item->price; ?>
<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value=""><br>
  Street Address:<br>
  <input type="text" name="address" value=""><br>
  City:<br>
  <input type="text" name="city" value=""><br>
```

Comment: you can pass your purchaseID on checkoutpage using `url query stirng` and do a select query there... and get your purchased items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avhieve what you want, catch a shopping basket in three ways:

1) Server side, on a SESSION, so once the user selects an item it must be stored in a SESSION, with its quantity.  I don't recommend to store prices on it, they shall be fetched from a data source in order to prevent user manipulation of forms.

```
$_SESSION['cart']['item']=$_POST['item_name']

$_SESSION['cart']['item_quantity']=$_POST['item_quantity']
```

2). Client side, on local Storage API, using Javascript.

```
localStorage.setItem("item", "ASUS M32CD DESKTOP");
```

3) Less recommended to store on a cookie, is a file created by the server and deployed on user's hard disk and accessed only by your server.